# Openstack installation failed for devstack stack.sh

Tags: openstack, devstack, keystone

I am using stack.sh from devstack site to install openstack all-in-one machine. After starting keystone, installation is failing at following step:

++ get_or_create_project admin default

+++ openstack --os-url=http://10.122.12.145:5000/v3 --os-identity-api-version=3 project create admin --domain=default --or-show -f value -c id

ERROR: openstack Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504) ++ local project_id= ++ echo + local admin_tenant=

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Could you please let me know if anyone has run in to this issue and possible solutions?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 3):

Worked after editing the no_proxy variable:

```
./unstack.sh
 export no_proxy=127.0.0.1,<your-IP>
./stack.sh
```

Comment: If that fixed the problem, please mark this as the correct answer.